# Can i use deionized water instead of distilled water

Tags: water

My question is really simple : can i use **deionized** water instead of **distilled** in experience ? 
Because i have a **air dehumidifier** at home and it produce a lot of **deionized** water 
I know that **deionized** water ($\ce{diH2O}$) is :

> Water that has had almost all of its mineral ions removed, such as cations like sodium, calcium, iron, and copper, and anions such as chloride and sulfate.

And **distilled** water ($\ce{dH2O}$) is :

> Water boiled and then condensed into a clean container, leaving solid contaminants behind

So basically the difference between $\ce{diH2O}$ and $\ce{dH2O}$ is that $\ce{dH2O}$ keep his ions mineral right ? 
Can i use **deionized** water anyway ? Or not ?

Comment: No, distilled H2O does not keep its mineral ions. Whether or not you can use deionized water depends on your application.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I need water to wash products (like crystal), and to use as reactant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Water from a dehumidifier is similar to distilled, in that it contains little in the way of dissolved materials.   It condensed on (typically) anodized aluminum,
and dripped through polymer collection trays into a bucket.

How clean is the bucket?  There may be residue from dust/lint etc.

It's water.   You can moisten plants, fish can swim in it, and it's pure enough
to drink or wash your windows (in fact, it's softer than most tap water, it
makes a good final rinse for windows).  I'd stick to deionized or distilled
for lab use, though, because those didn't come from a dirty bucket.